# Only getting a subset of audit logs from a given user

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am trying to get audit logs from specific users. In Azure AD I can see much more than 25 entries and NextPageResult is null on the returned object. I use following code:

```
var directoryAudits = await graphClient.AuditLogs.DirectoryAudits.Request().Filter($"targetResources/any(c:c/id eq '{"5f88d011-3ea2-xx-bf46-xx"}')").GetAsync();
```

However I only get 25 result back in the result set. Any pointers whats wrong here?

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid you need to call the api directly to check if there are only 25 items. Per my test in my side, I really get the same count in http request and graph client. And you may also double check in your azure portal. https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HQNM.png

Comment: I think it maybe the way I filter I need to investigate further. I think targetRessouece means to who the action was applied to, and not who did it. So in the azure portal I see a lot of audits on my user, but many of the audits is where I update another user etc. So my code dont get all audits from a given user, but all audits applied to a user?

Comment: Sorry I can't understand it well as I'm not familar with this api, I'm afraid [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/directoryaudit?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) may help you.....